# How to reference the Amazon Data Pipeline name?

Tags: amazon-data-pipeline

Is it possible to use the name of an Amazon Data Pipeline as a variable inside the Data Pipeline itself? If yes, how can you do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't refer to the name. You can refer to the pipeline ID using the expression `@pipelineId`. For example, you could define a ShellCommandActivity to print the pipeline ID:

```
{
  "id": "ExampleActivity",
  "name": "ExampleActivity",
  "runsOn": { "ref": "SomeEc2Resource" },
  "type": "ShellCommandActivity",
  "command": "echo \"Hello from #{@pipelineId}\""
}
```